# Plotting Dictionaries values when values represent number and color

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

The dictionary shows how many pieces of fruit and what colour the elipse should be. 
I was looking at the sample code as shown below to plot the dict

example:
my_dict {'apples': [20, '#2E9127'], 'pears': [3, '#FB9A27'], 'cherries': [7, '#187429']}

so this way the plot will show 20 dots of that color #2E9127.

key is not relevant at this point but value1 is the count and v2 is the hex color
so when I make the elipse ([graph below or click this link](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/shapes_and_collections/ellipse_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-ellipse-demo-py)) I want to see 20 times  #2E9127, 3 times #FB9A27 and 7 times #187429.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

    NUM = len(my_dict) #but dont want total random dots so thinking this is 
                          #sum of value 1 possibly in a loop


     #example from matplotlib
     # so clearly dont want random np values
    ells = [Ellipse(xy=np.random.rand(2) * 10,
                    width=np.random.rand(), height=np.random.rand(),
                    angle=np.random.rand() * 360)
            for i in range(NUM)]

    #ME HAVING A CRACK!
    # 
    ells = [Ellipse(xy=my_dict(2) * 10,
                    width=np.random.rand(), height=np.random.rand(),
                    angle=np.random.rand() * 360,facecolor=y)
            for i in range(NUM)]


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
    for e in ells:
        ax.add_artist(e)
        e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
        e.set_alpha(np.random.rand())
        e.set_facecolor(np.random.rand(3))

    ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear how the dictionary and the ellipses relate. Which ellipses should have which color? Since you have 250 ellipses and the sum of all values is only 30 it is not even deducible from the example.

Comment: sorry thats the sample code from matplotlib -- i took it down

Comment: I was thinking maybe I am better off converting to a list
        func = ()    
        for (i,j) in p:
            func = func + (int(i),j)

        print (func)

Comment: Now it is even less clear because the code is missing.

Comment: ok 1 sec let me edit

Comment: Now the first comment still applies. Maybe you start with the first sentence, "I want to plot the following dictionary into an elipse" does not even make sense. So just explain clearly what you want to have.

Comment: I dont get what you mean, apples are 20 and a given color, so the elipse should show 20 dots in that color, maybe im better of converting to a list?

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to draw as many ellipses as the sum of the values from the dictionary would give. (20 apples, 7 cherries, 3 pears)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

my_dict ={'apples': [20, '#2E9127'], 'pears': [3, '#FB9A27'], 'cherries': [7, 'crimson']}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    color = val[1]
    for i in range(val[0]):
        el = Ellipse(xy=np.random.rand(2) * 10,
                    width=np.random.rand(), height=np.random.rand(),
                    angle=np.random.rand() * 360, color=color)
        ax.add_artist(el)


ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

I made the cherries red to be able to see them clearly:

[image]